# When using Istio on EKS, how can I restrict the IPs in the security group rules that are created?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, istio, amazon-eks

I just setup Istio on EKS. I noticed that the gateway controller (is that what I should call it?) creates an ELB and a corresponding security group  that allows incoming traffic on a few different ports:

[image: Security Group Rules]

Right now, all of these rules allow traffic from everywhere (0.0.0.0/0), but I'd like to be able to restrict this to my VPN server. Is there a way to specify a security group id (ideally), or at least an IP for these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to specify the Source IP for Inbound Rules of default Istio's Ingress Gateway during installation/upgrade of Istio via Helm.

You realize it by adjusting default values of Service object kind associated with   your istio-ingressgateway pod:

Here is how I'm doing it via Helm install:

1. Install with helm using --set option to override default values (here default values of 'gateways' subcharts):

> ```
>  $ helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio-maxi --namespace istio-system \
>   --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerSourceRanges=143.231.0.0/16
> ```

2. Here are the resulting Inbound Rules of ELB standing in front of
   Istio Ingress Gateway seen in AWS console:

[image]

**Important note:**

The [loadBalancerSourceRanges](https://github.com/istio/istio/commit/9708b61413eb07d3f5801a56811368a726d13d45) field is available by now still in a **Pre-release** state (1.1.0-snapshot.5) of Istio helm chart

Comment: Thanks. I ended up modifying the helm subchart before I saw your answer, but this seems like a better approach.